How to edit lines of bar chart in apache superset based on threshold
***I am unable to customise colour of bar char in Apache super-set dashboard. The goal is if count/sum/avg is greater then 100 the colour should be blue of the line, elif greate then 1200 the colour should be red of the line and so on. I have tried to alter yaml files but failed.
Here is my yaml file. I am currently trying to modify vaccine dashboard bar chart (vaccine candidate per phase). The colour for count should be dynamic. Any suggestion? What should be yaml file, SQL query? or any changes needed in react components???***
....
description: ''
chartsInScope:
- 9
- 10
- 11
- 12
- 13
- 14
- 15
- 66
tabsInScope:
- TAB-BCIJF4NvgQ


id: NATIVE_FILTER-EWNH3M70z
controlValues:
enableEmptyFilter: false
defaultToFirstItem: false
multiSelect: true
searchAllOptions: false
inverseSelection: false
name: Clinical Stage
filterType: filter_select
targets:

column:
name: clinical_stage
datasetUuid: 974b7a1c-22ea-49cb-9214-97b7dbd511e0
defaultDataMask:
extraFormData: {}
filterState: {}
ownState: {}
cascadeParentIds: []
scope:
rootPath:

ROOT_ID
excluded: []
type: NATIVE_FILTER
description: ''
chartsInScope:


9
10
11
12
13
14
15
66
tabsInScope:
TAB-BCIJF4NvgQ
color_scheme: supersetColors
label_colors:
"0": "#D3B3DA"
"1": "#9EE5E5"


Pre-clinical: "#1FA8C9"
Phase II or Combined I/II: "#454E7C"
Phase I: "#5AC189"
Phase III: "#FF7F44"
Authorized: "#666666"
root: "#1FA8C9"
Protein subunit: "#454E7C"
Phase II: "#5AC189"
Pre-clinical: "#FF7F44"
Phase III: "#666666"
Phase I: "#E04355"
Phase I/II: "#FCC700"
Inactivated virus: "#A868B7"
Virus-like particle: "#3CCCCB"
Replicating bacterial vector: "#A38F79"
DNA-based: "#8FD3E4"
RNA-based vaccine: "#A1A6BD"
Authorized: "#ACE1C4"
Non-replicating viral vector: "#FEC0A1"
Replicating viral vector: "#B2B2B2"
Unknown: "#EFA1AA"
Live attenuated virus: "#FDE380"
COUNT(*): "#D1C6BC"
version: 1.0.0



The count is basically responsible for giving color to whole bar chart
I have tried modifying yaml file, modifying histogram in react portion
